# BI Publisher conditional field masking

Tags: peoplesoft, bi-publisher

I have the following code on a field in a Peoplesoft BI Publisher RTF template where it is masking the last 4 digits of the Bank Account number.

```
<?xdofx:lpad('',length(Bank_Account__)-4,'*')?> 
<?xdoxslt:rtrim(xdoxslt:right(Bank_Account__,4))?>
```

The problem is that sometimes the total Bank Account number length is less than 4 digits and when this happens it causes an negative array error on the lpad function to occur.

Can I wrap some kind of conditional IF statement around this where it will check the length of the bank account number and if it is longer than 5 digits than mask the last 4 digits, else (for Bank Account numbers less than 5 digits) just mask the last 2 digits. What would this look like?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I should add that the existing code above is already wrapped in the following IF statement:

```
<?if@inlines:Bank_Account__!=''?>
```

So the entire statement is:

```
<?if@inlines:Bank_Account__!=''?>
    <?xdofx:lpad('',length(Bank_Account__)-4,'*')?> 
    <?xdoxslt:rtrim(xdoxslt:right(Bank_Account__,4))?>
<?end if?>
```

I would just like to add in the conditional logic to check the bank account length and subsequently perform either of the above masking.

**EDIT 2:**
Here is my setup with your suggested changes, but I don't think I have the logic nested right, and the syntax may also be an issue.

[image]

**Edit 3:**

Here is the modified code, and the resulting error message:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually it's the last four of the number that are shown, not masked. Any time I see an account number anywhere, it always shows the last four digits.

Comment: Yes thats what I mean't, the problem is some of the account numbers are less than 4 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statements can be nested, but since BIP does not have an else clause, the second if conditions has to check for the negative case.

Maybe this might work:

```
<?if@inlines:Bank_Account__!=''?>
    <?if@inlines:string-length(Bank_Account__)>4?>
        <?xdofx:lpad('',length(Bank_Account__)-4,'*')?><?xdoxslt:rtrim(xdoxslt:right(Bank_Account__,4))?>
    <?end if?>
    <?if@inlines:string-length(Bank_Account__)<=4?>
        <?xdofx:lpad('','2','*')?><?xdoxslt:rtrim(xdoxslt:right(Bank_Account__,string-length(Bank_Account__)-2))?>
    <?end if?>
<?end if?>
```

Update: Here is a screenshot of what I got:

[image]

Here is the xml snippet I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <record>
    <Bank_Account__>123456</Bank_Account__>
  </record>
    <record>
    <Bank_Account__>12345</Bank_Account__>
  </record>
    <record>
    <Bank_Account__>1234</Bank_Account__>
  </record>
    <record>
    <Bank_Account__>123</Bank_Account__>
  </record>
    <record>
    <Bank_Account__>12</Bank_Account__>
  </record>
</root>
```

Download working files from [here](https://transfer.sh/jxd8z/inp.zip)

There are some [more functions](https://cleartext.blogspot.com/2009/07/bip-if-then-else.html) available for other ways to implement this requirement.

Comment: Are you missing a closing IF `<?end if?>` above ? I set this up 2 If statements, in the header if contains `<?if@inlines:Bank_Account__!=''?>` and then I am putting the nested If logic on the field next to it. Is that correct, or can the entire If (for the length greater than 4 case) be put into the main If field? I'll edit the post above (Edit 2) for clarity...

Comment: I have formatted the earlier answer. There is one outer If.endif, and two more if.endifs inside that.

Comment: Thanks - I modified the code as you suggested however I am getting the negative error error when I try to preview the file. Please see Edit 3 above for the changes I made in the Field Browser and the resulting error message. In this case the Account number field is only 3 digits long so it should be masking just the first 2 digits.

Comment: Updated answer again. string-length has to be used instead of length, inside if conditions. Download my files from here : https://transfer.sh/jxd8z/inp.zip

Comment: @RanjithR regarding your comment about BIP not supporting else clauses: You can use a `<?choose:?><?when:expression?>'true'<?end when?><?otherwise?>'false'<?end otherwise?><?end choose?>` structure or use `<?xdoxslt:ifelse(expression, 'true', 'false')?>` and `<?xdofx:if expression then 'true' else 'false'?>`

Comment: @RanjithR this works as expected! Thanks! Trying to learn more about coding with BI Publisher templates. I see that both SQL syntax and XSL syntax can be used in the RTF template. If there are any good resources you would recommend, feel free to provide a link.